# Javascript and ajax issue in chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium version 4.8.3. I am trying to select a dropdown list in https://eservices.tn.gov.in/eservicesnew/land/areg.html. In normal chrome browser i can able to select district value from the drowpdown. During troubleshooting I found that it makes a [ajax call](https://eservices.tn.gov.in/eservicesnew/land/ajax.html?page=ruralservice&ser=dist&lang=en) to load data in to the drop down. Am not able to get the option value in selenium because ajax call is not done in chromedriver. I added two options

1. options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
2. options.add_argument('javascript.enabled=True')

But it's not worked.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument('javascript.enabled=True')
DRIVER_PATH = r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://eservices.tn.gov.in/eservicesnew/land/areg.html")

abc = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="districtCode"]')
all_options = abc.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"option")
for option in all_options:
    print(option.text)
    print("Value is: %s" % option.get_attribute("value"))
    option.click()
```

Comment: AJAX/Javascript are performed by the browser.  This has nothing to do with the driver.  When JS is used to update the DOM you need to use WebDriverWaits with expected conditions.  (in this case you may need to deal with stale elements or just use a standard sleep like in the answer below...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebDriver opens chrome in incognito mode by default. To fix your issue, rather than using incognito mode, use the same chrome profile which your system would use when you open chrome manually.

- **Working code:**

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\<username here>\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://eservices.tn.gov.in/eservicesnew/land/areg.html")
time.sleep(3)
abc = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="districtCode"]')
all_options = abc.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"option")
for option in all_options:
    print(option.text)
    print("Value is: %s" % option.get_attribute("value"))
    option.click()
```

- **Console output:**

```
Please Select ...
Value is: 
--Select District--
Value is: 00
Ariyalur
Value is: 17
Chengalpattu
Value is: 35
Chennai
Value is: 02
Coimbatore
Value is: 12
Cuddalore
Value is: 18
Dharmapuri
Value is: 05
Dindigul
Value is: 13
Erode
Value is: 10
Kallakurichi
Value is: 33
Kancheepuram
Value is: 03
Kanniyakumari
Value is: 30
Karur
Value is: 14
Krishnagiri
Value is: 31
Madurai
Value is: 24
Mayiladuthurai
Value is: 38
Nagapattinam
Value is: 19
Namakkal
Value is: 09
Perambalur
Value is: 16
Pudukkottai
Value is: 22
Ramanathapuram
Value is: 27
Ranipet
Value is: 37
Salem
Value is: 08
Sivagangai
Value is: 23
Tenkasi
Value is: 34
Thanjavur
Value is: 21
Theni
Value is: 25
The Nilgiris
Value is: 11
Thiruvarur
Value is: 20
Thoothukkudi
Value is: 28
Tiruchirappalli
Value is: 15
Tirunelveli
Value is: 29
Tirupathur
Value is: 36
Tiruppur
Value is: 32
Tiruvallur
Value is: 01
Tiruvannamalai
Value is: 06
Vellore
Value is: 04
Viluppuram
Value is: 07
Virudhunagar
Value is: 26

Process finished with exit code 0
```

- **How to locate the browser profile path:**
  Open the browser manually --> in the address bar type, "chrome://version/". Get the profile path as shown below:

[image]